# Double value not correct on Device

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, double

```
int min = Int32.Parse(minutebox.Text);
double kj = Convert.ToDouble(a.kj);
double res = ((kj * op.koerpergewicht) * min);
textbox.Text = res.ToString();
```

Shows me the correct number (with its punctuation -> i. e. 2.33) on my English WP7-Emulator. However it doesn't work on my Device, which is set to German.

The value is correct but the point, comma or whatever in that double value isn't shown correct.

43.22 on Emulator -> 4322 on Device

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> However it doesn't work on my Device, which is set to German.

It will be using the German symbols by default. If you want to always use "." as the decimal point, you should consider specifying the invariant culture for parsing and potentially formatting too.

It's hard to correct your code without knowing what `kj` is, but I'd suggest using

```
double value = double.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Do calculation...
textBox.Text = result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Are you really *sure* you want to override the culture of the device though? It doesn't sound like a great idea to me. Of course if you're fetching the text from somewhere else, you may want to *parse* it with the invariant culture, but still format it in the device default culture.

Comment: imho, if Clue is coding for German (hint: koerpergewicht =. body weight) with **KJ** or **kj** likely being used to represent *kilojoule* ... hence, one would not want to lock in the *period* because German uses a *comma* where English speaking persons use the *decimal point*; German uses *periods* or *spaces* where English speaking persons would use *commas*, example `1 234,5` or `1.234,5` instead of `1,234.5`.

Comment: @gerryLowry: That's exactly my point. I suspect the OP's original text *is* using a ".", but it's parsing that as a thousands separator. It's not clear what the OP's input is, or how exactly he wants the output rendered.

Comment: a.kj is coming in as a String.

Comment: @ Clue it would be best if you could should several samples of what you're typing in and what you're getting back on both your Win-phone-7 emulator and on your Win-7-phone device.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet if Clue is parsing as German, then i'd *expect* `43.22` to throw an exception because it's short the third digit, i.e., it should be in the German culture `43.22x` since the first part `43.` suggests 43 thousand and *something*.  One possibilty, the settings of the emulator are different from the settings of the physical device. FWIW, i'm *guessing* because i do not have a win-phone-7.

Comment: I currently use a workaround, by dividing the double, which does not show up correctly on my device, by 1000.

Sample: 473,55 on Emulator -> 47355 on Device - and when I write the code like: `double res = Convert.ToDouble(((kj * op.koerpergewicht) * min)/1000);` I get 473,55.

Comment: I just see that the number is not correct on my device anymore, when I set my device to English.

Comment: @gerryLowry: I believe that the thousands separator is basically ignored. For example, if I parse "12,34" in an English locale, that just parses to 1234.

Comment: @Clue: Did you try the code I suggested? You absolutely should *not* be manually working around this as per your other code.

Comment: @John Skeet you're correct ... i ran `double value = double.Parse("12,34", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` in [LINQPad 4](http://www.linqpad.net/) and the result, to my surprise, was `1234` ... imho, it should fail to parse. `1234` is also the result for `.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`. [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) and [CultureInfo.NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat.aspx) currently shed no light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I got further:

First of all, I parsed all my Strings do double like this

```
op.mydouble = Double.Parse(rawkg,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The InvariantCulture part is very important.

The rest of my calculations went like this:

```
 double res = 0; double reskcal = 0;
                double reskj;

                    res = ((kj * op.koerpergewicht) * min);
                    reskj = Convert.ToDouble(res, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    reskcal = Convert.ToDouble((res * 0.239), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Problem now is, that reskcal is returning me:

```
11,317845
```

Math.Round(11,317845,2) didn't help.

Comment: `11,317845` is the German equivalent of the English `11.317845`.  What do you mean by `Math.Round` did not help? the answer should be `11,32`.

Comment: @ Clue yes and no; i suspect it rounded it with zero effect because as Jon Skeet correctly suggested, the comma is being ignored. in English, `11,317845` and `11,317,845` are equally acceptable ways of writing 11 million, et cetera. you may want to try this *cheater's* experiment: `Double double007 = Double.Parse("11,317845.007"); // 11317845.007` and `Double clue = Math.Round(double007,2); // 11317845.01`; i say *cheater's* because i'm cheating because one can not write `Math.Round(11,317845.007,2);`.